# Dynamic columns generation on the basis of rows of a table in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with four columns item_id, color, size, weight, I want to show my table rows into one row like item1,color1,size1,weight1,item2,color2,...........,item4,color4,size4,weight4 ...

Following is my table

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| item_id | color  | size   | weight |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1 | blue   | large  | 65     |
|       2 | orange | large  | 57     |
|       3 | red    | small  | 12     |
|       4 | violet | medium | 34     |
```

My desired result will be

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------++---------+--------+--------+
| item_id1| color1| size1 | weight1| item_id2 | color2  | size2   | weight2 |....
+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+---------------
|       1 | blue   | large| 65     |      2   | orange  | large   | 57      |...
+---------+--------+--------+--------+    +---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do that in SQL `SELECT` because by definition the number of columns there is fixed. Why do you want to reshape the results (ie, update the presentation) on the database level?

Comment: You should be asking yourself why you need to do this? As mentioned, SQL works with a fixed column set. You could do this using dynamic SQL but it would be very unnecessary and messy.

Comment: What can you do with that row that you couldn't do also with the original dataset? What happens if your table contains thousands of rows? Looks impractical to me.

Comment: @TToni yes you are right if there are thounsands of records then its a issue, but in my case my maximum rows will be only upto  15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get this result, you will need to do a few things:

- [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the current data
- [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the result from the unpivot
- use dynamic SQL since you will have an unknown number of rows

Since you are using SQL Server 2005+ you can use CROSS APPLY to unpivot the data, this process takes your multiple columns of `item_id`, `color`, `size` and `weight` and converts them into multiple rows:

```
select col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(50)) col,
     value
from 
(
   select item_id as seq, item_id, color, size, weight
   from yourtable
) d
cross apply
(
   values
    ('item_id', cast(item_id as varchar(50))),
    ('color', color),
    ('size', size),
    ('weight', cast(weight as varchar(50)))
) c (col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e07aa/4). This gives a result:

```
|       COL |  VALUE |
----------------------
| item_id_1 |      1 |
|   color_1 |   blue |
|    size_1 |  large |
|  weight_1 |     65 |
| item_id_2 |      2 |
|   color_2 | orange |
|    size_2 |  large |
|  weight_2 |     57 |
| item_id_3 |      3 |
```

As you can see from the result you now have multiple rows in based off your original data. The `COL` values are the values that you will use to PIVOT.  The full dynamic SQL code will be similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+'_'+cast(item_id as varchar(10))) 
                    from yourtable
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'item_id', 0 union all
                      select 'color', 1 union all
                      select 'size', 2 union all
                      select 'weight', 3 
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by item_id, col, so
                    order by item_id, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select col+''_''+cast(seq as varchar(50)) col,
                  value
                from 
                (
                  select item_id as seq, item_id, color, size, weight
                  from yourtable
                ) d
                cross apply
                (
                  values
                    (''item_id'', cast(item_id as varchar(50))),
                    (''color'', color),
                    (''size'', size),
                    (''weight'', cast(weight as varchar(50)))
                ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e07aa/5). The final result is:

```
| ITEM_ID_1 | COLOR_1 | SIZE_1 | WEIGHT_1 | ITEM_ID_2 | COLOR_2 | SIZE_2 | WEIGHT_2 | ITEM_ID_3 | COLOR_3 | SIZE_3 | WEIGHT_3 | ITEM_ID_4 | COLOR_4 | SIZE_4 | WEIGHT_4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |    blue |  large |       65 |         2 |  orange |  large |       57 |         3 |     red |  small |       12 |         4 |  violet | medium |       34 |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it programmatically and you don't know the number of rows try this :

```
DECLARE @I INT, @END INT, @DATA nvarchar(max), @TEMPSTR nvarchar(max), @DynamicTableSQL nvarchar(max)
SET @I = 1
SET @DATA = ''
SET @TEMPSTR = ''

SELECT @END = MAX(item_id) from items


SET @DynamicTableSQL = 'DECLARE @DynamicTable TABLE('
WHILE @I <= @END
BEGIN
    --SELECT @I
    SET @TEMPSTR = (select CAST(item_id as nvarchar) + ',''' + color + ''',''' + size + ''',' + cast(weight as nvarchar) + ',' FROM items WHERE item_id = @I)
    SET @DynamicTableSQL = @DynamicTableSQL + 'item_id_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10))+ ' INT ,' + 'color_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10))+ ' NVARCHAR(15) ,'+ 'size_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10))+ ' NVARCHAR(15) ,'+ 'weight_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10))+ ' INT ,'
    SET @DATA += @TEMPSTR
    SELECT @I = @I + 1
END

SET @DynamicTableSQL = SUBSTRING(@DynamicTableSQL, 0, LEN(@DynamicTableSQL))
SET @DynamicTableSQL = @DynamicTableSQL + ') '
SET @DATA = SUBSTRING(@DATA, 0, LEN(@DATA))
SET @DynamicTableSQL = @DynamicTableSQL + ' INSERT INTO @DynamicTable VALUES (' + @DATA + ')'

SET @DynamicTableSQL = @DynamicTableSQL + ' SELECT * FROM @DynamicTable '

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @DynamicTableSQL
```

Comment: However, as soon as you have more than 4 rows of data, you would need to cross apply every additional one.

Comment: Sure ! is that a problem ?

Comment: Well, yes. If this table is being populated on the fly and this script is being called from a stored procedure. Somewhere you need to dynamically identify the number of cross apply's required.

Comment: Yes you are right you can do that and create a temp table with a dynamic layout. It's explained in the link see my edit.

Comment: Hi Arno thanks for your response but in my scanario I dont know the total number of rows...